# Reuse search result from previous view

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to wrap my hand around how to do the following in Django:

Let's say I have a view that accepts a GET request with search parameters, like:

```
def search(request, id):
    another_model = get_object_or_404(models.AnotherModel, id=id)
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'submit' in request.GET:
        result = {}

        # Expensive db operation to filter based on search query
        # Populates result

        return render(request, "result.html", {
            'result': result,
            'form': forms.ConfirmationForm(another_model=another_model)})

    form = forms.SearchForm(None, another_model=another_model)

    return render(request, "search.html", {'form': form})
```

When receiving the search query it performs some expensive database operations based on the GET params. The result and a form get passed to a template for rendering.

In the template the form action is set up to post to a different view:

```
def confirm(request, id):
    another_model = get_object_or_404(models.AnotherModel, id=id)
    form = forms. ConfirmationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('done', id)    

    # How to:
    # return render(request, "result.html", {
    #    'result': result,
    #    'form': forms.ConfirmationForm(another_model=another_model)})
```

So far confirm() only works if the form was valid. Where I struggle is how can I 'recreate'
the response based on the previous search query within confirm() if the form fails. 
Do I have to somehow cache the result from search() so I don't have to run the expensive
operation again in confirm()? Or is it just a matter of restructuring the code?

(Hopefully the explanation of the problem isn't too confusing!)

Comment: You'd like to redirect the user back to your search view (without recalculating the result) if `form.is_valid()` is not true in your confirm function?

Comment: No, sorry, not like that. I need to display the same result page with form errors. But in order to do that confirm() needs to have the result from search() (see return render(request, "result.html", {
            'result': result, ... )

Comment: I guess one way of doing it is to post the form back to search() instead of having a confirm view() and check for request.method='POST'. But then I will still need to cache the previous search result or somehow pass on the previous GET query so I can recreate the result which I would like to avoid. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes. unless the information is included in the form, I think you will need to cache the result or store it in the user's session as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do it

1. Cache the result
2. Store the result in the user's session
3. Include the relevant information in the form - either using hidden or read-only fields.

Comment: I think I will try a combination of caching and passing the orignal GET query on to the form which then includes it as part of the form's action url. This way I can re-create the result in case it drops out of cache. Hmm. Will get back to you once I have tried this approach. Thanks.